# 1.8.8 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin cannot be null

Tags: java, minecraft

I have this error on my plugin which I have been trying to resolve for a long time, and I cannot find the solution which is why I have come to find help here! I've this error:

```
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:310) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1630) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:31) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24] at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInWindowClick.a(SourceFile:9) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:715) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin cannot be null
at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.validate(CraftScheduler.java:397) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.runTaskTimer(CraftScheduler.java:123) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(CraftScheduler.java:119) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.scheduleSyncDelayedTask(CraftScheduler.java:102) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
at tech.mssteur.ktcp9.objects.Game.launch(Game.java:88) ~[?:?]
at tech.mssteur.ktcp9.guis.ConfigMenu.lambda$init$1(ConfigMenu.java:61) ~[?:?]
at fr.minuskube.inv.ClickableItem.run(ClickableItem.java:26) ~[?:?]
at fr.minuskube.inv.InventoryManager$InvListener.lambda$onInventoryClick$2(InventoryManager.java:140) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:176) ~[?:?]
at fr.minuskube.inv.InventoryManager$InvListener.onInventoryClick(InventoryManager.java:140) ~[?:?]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[?:?]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
... 15 more
```

Here is the Game class: https://pastebin.com/YkCPsXPN
Here is the Main class: https://pastebin.com/WxGWaLUA

If anyone has a solution to resolve this error I would be very grateful to them, thanks

Comment: Do you use an IDe and have you tried to debug your code by yourself?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin cannot be null` seems that the plugin could not initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IllegalArgumentException usually gets thrown when the developer is giving wrong parameter arguments into a method. In this case the argument `plugin` is `NULL`. When looking at the stack trace we see that the problem is in the `load`-method of the `Game` class as stated by this line:

```
at tech.mssteur.ktcp9.objects.Game.launch(Game.java:88) ~[?:?]
```

From the line before we see that the violating method-call is `scheduleSyncDelayedTask`

```
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.scheduleSyncDelayedTask(CraftScheduler.java:102)
```

The method `scheduleSyncDelayedTask` takes a `plugin`-argument which needs to be initialized. In your case it isn't.

You have two constructors initializing your `Game`-object. One of those is setting the `plugin`-field you are using when calling `scheduleSyncDelayedTask`. You are probably using the default constructor without arguments. Hence, your `plugin` is `NULL`.

Comment: I initialized "plugin" like this: 
```private Main plugin;
public Game(Main plugin){ this.plugin = plugin; }```
You can see the full class here: https://pastebin.com/YkCPsXPN

Comment: Yes `plugin` gets set in that constructor. But you are not using that constructor. `public Game game = new Game();`